# Visual C++ project dependencies with multiple build configurations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have a VC++ 2005 solution with two library projects A & B (which emit A.lib & B.lib), and an application project. The application has two build configurations release_A & release_B, where release_A uses A.lib and release_B uses B.lib.

The problem is that I want to have project dependencies so that application depends on A & B, meaning that the build order will build A or B as needed before the application. I have already set the Configuration Manager so that A is only built for release_A, and B only builds for release_B, but when I build configuration release_A, I will still tend to get errors that B.lib doesn't exist. The project dependency doesn't seem to have that level of smartness, and it doesn't allow me to manually set the build order either.

Is there any way around this other than remembering to manually build A/B first and then build the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project settings for the application, go to `Linker -> General` and set `Link Library Dependencies` to `No`. This will suppress the automatic linking against the dependencies, though it means that you will have to manually add the libraries by name to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`